# Swift 4, iOS how to detect label height after added string value

Tags: ios, label, swift4, cell

in UICollectionView my cell's size must be 150+label.height. Now I'm using custom layout to calculate height = 150 if image exists inImageView if not height = 100. It's easy. But how to calculate label.height when i don't know what text i'll fetch from Api? Is there any function to get that?

customLayout.swift

```
let photoHeight = delegate.collectionView(collectionView, heightForPhotoAtIndexPath: indexPath) > 0 ? 150 : 100
let height = cellPadding * 2 + CGFloat(photoHeight) + (labelHeight??????)
```

Comment: you should consider using auto layout to have self sizing cells

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate label height using below function

```
extension UILabel {

    func heightToFitContent() -> CGFloat {

        self.numberOfLines = 0
        self.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        let maximumLabelSize : CGSize = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let expectedLabelSize : CGSize = self.sizeThatFits(maximumLabelSize);


        self.sizeToFit()

        return expectedLabelSize.height
    }
}
```

call this function in UI thread. Hope this helps.

Comment: self is UILabel and I need spacing in my case